# Impossible to fill a column in many-to-many relationship with @Formula

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I have 2 classes, Evaluation and Reponse, linked with a many-to-many relationship.
The code of Evaluation looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Evaluation implements Serializable {

private Long id;

@ManyToMany
public List<Reponse> getListOfReponses() {
    return listOfReponses;
}

@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Evaluation_Reponse er, Reponse r, WHERE er.Evaluation_id = id AND r.id = er.listOfReponses_id AND r.correct = 1)")
public Integer getNbCorrectAnswers() {
return nbCorrectAnswers;
```

}

Correct is a property of Reponse and is a boolean.

As you can see, I wrote a hibernate formula to fill the nbCorrectAnswers column. However, when I save an Evaluation, everything works fine except that the nbCorrectAnswers column stays empty.

So, could you tell me what's wrong in the formula, or how to fill correctly my whole table ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

formula is always readonly. hibernate assumes you have some other code/entity which inserts the values. AFAIK a formula is also only evaluated when loading from the database.